# No instance for ariving from use of 'next'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I noticed that a function I wrote is now not working, despite using it successfully on other occasions.

My test file (made one just to test this issue) looks like this:

```
import System.Random
generator = next . snd
```

This results in the error

```
No instance for (RandomGen g0) arising from a use of ‘next’
The type variable ‘g0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  generator :: (a, g0) -> (Int, g0) (bound at Test.hs:2:1)
Note: there is a potential instance available:
  instance RandomGen StdGen -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘next’
In the expression: next . snd
In an equation for ‘generator’: generator = next . snd
```

The weird thing is that if I open ghci and type:

```
import System.Random
let generator = next . snd
```

Everything works just fine. What exactly am I missing?

Edit: Also tried this and it works just fine:

```
generator something = next (snd something)
```

Comment: ahhh you found a [Monomorphism Restriction Instance](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) ;) - run `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction` in GHCi and you will get the same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is because of the [Monomorphism Restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction)

It's a technical issue (please explore the link if you are interested in the details) and normally you'll never see because you add signatures or write down the arguments (not *point-free* style) in your modules - and in GHCi it's disabled - you got a bit unlucky here.

for newer versions of GHC this is enabled by default for compiled modules but disabled for GHCi (so it will use defaults as epsilonhalbe told you)

To get the same behavior you can run

```
:set -XMonomorphismRestriction
```

in GHCi

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a type signature, ghci is using defaults therefore this does not happen there