# Haskell: error by using point-operator to combine two functions

Tags: haskell, io, output

i just started Haskell and ran into a problem with (.).

```
let myPrint = putStrLn . show
myPrint ("Hello World!")
<interactive>:171:10:
Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `[Char]'
In the first argument of `myPrint', namely `("hello Wordl!")'
In the expression: myPrint ("hello Wordl!")
In an equation for `it': it = myPrint ("hello Wordl!")
```

The information about my defined function prints:

```
Prelude> :info myPrint
myPrint :: () -> IO ()
```

Shouldn't the output be:

```
myPrint:: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

Comment: seems another one hit the Monomorphism-Restriction - use `let myPrint a = putStrLn $ show a`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643445/no-instance-for-ariving-from-use-of-next/36643992#36643992

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an old GHCi/Hugs interpreter, where the dreaded monomorphism restriction applies. I'd recommend you update it.

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let myPrint = putStrLn . show
Prelude> :t myPrint
myPrint :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

Comment: add `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction` for the observed behavior ;)

Comment: (not sure but on older compilers `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` might work too)

Comment: @Carsten I have no desire to observe it! :-P

Comment: to be honest I'm not 100% sure if I agree - the difference between the compiler and GHCi here is the cause of quite a few questions here (and indeed it's puzzling) - maybe you know it right away: is there a switch to activate warnings on defaults in GHCi?

Comment: @Carsten I agree that the mismatch between GHCi and GHC generates several questions here on SO, perhaps too many. A "monomorphism warning" could be nice to have in GHCi... I don't know if that is already implemented.

Comment: I think you get warnings (with `-Wall`) when GHC is *defaulting*  and that would help here to - I think I saw the switch to use this in GHCi (Wall) but I cannot find it right now

Comment: @Carsten `-fwarn-monomorphism-restriction` https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html